# Magnitude of current

Tags: electromagnetism

The current of a germanium diode at room temperature is 100uA at a voltage of -1V. Predict the magnitude of the current for voltages of 0.2V and -0.2V at room temperature. Repeat the prediction for operation at 20°C above room temperature?

I had tried i=Is(e^[V/nVt] but i am getting +100uA for -0.2V and -300mA for +0.2V but the answer is -100uA for -0.2V and +300mA for 0.2V. Please help me with signs

Comment: This is not a math problem. Isn't there a stack exchange for EEs?

Comment: Sorry but it's urgent can you please try to help me?